How to preload input fields based on a selected variant in a dynamic selection screen in SAP ABAP?
I have a SAP ABAP program that dynamically generates input fields for wage types on a selection screen. Users can manually add wage types by clicking an "Add" button. Below is a snippet of the code:

DEFINE aline.
  selection-screen: begin of line.
  selection-screen comment (11) lbl_&1 FOR FIELD inp&1 modif id l&1.
  parameters: inp&1(39) type c modif id l&1.
  SELECT-OPTIONS  inp10&1 FOR gv_lgart modif id l&1 no intervals matchcode object ZH_T512W_06.
  selection-screen position 79. " Push button moved towards the right
  selection-screen pushbutton (7) pb_&1 user-command add
     modif id a&1. " Increased button width to align properly
  selection-screen end of line.
END-OF-DEFINITION.

DATA gv_lgart TYPE lgart.
RANGES rangee FOR gv_lgart.
TABLES sscrfields.
DATA inp_name TYPE string.
DATA inp_code TYPE string.
DATA wt_code  TYPE string.
DATA lines    TYPE n LENGTH 2.
DATA: BEGIN OF ls_wage_type,
        name  TYPE string,
        codes LIKE rangee[],
      END OF ls_wage_type.
FIELD-SYMBOLS <fs_name>  TYPE any.
FIELD-SYMBOLS <fs_codes> TYPE any.
CONSTANTS max_lines TYPE i VALUE 20.
DATA lt_wage_types LIKE TABLE OF ls_wage_type.
DATA fldname       TYPE string.
DATA cnt           TYPE n LENGTH 2.
FIELD-SYMBOLS <fld> TYPE any.

SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF BLOCK b05 WITH FRAME TITLE text-t05.
aline 01.
aline 02.
aline 03.
aline 04.
aline 05.
aline 06.
aline 07.
aline 08.
aline 09.
aline 10.
aline 11.
aline 12.
aline 13.
aline 14.
aline 15.
aline 16.
aline 17.
aline 18.
aline 19.
aline 20.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK b05.

*---------------------------------------------------- Push Button
AT SELECTION-SCREEN.
  CASE sscrfields-ucomm.
    WHEN 'ADD'.
      CHECK lines LT max_lines.
      " Dynamically assign the input fields
      CONCATENATE 'INP' lines INTO inp_name.
      CONCATENATE 'INP10' lines INTO inp_code.

      CONCATENATE inp_code '[]' INTO wt_code.

      ASSIGN (inp_name) TO <fs_name>.
      ASSIGN (wt_code) TO <fs_codes>.

      " Ensure the dynamic fields are accessible
      IF sy-subrc = 0.
        " Populate wage type structure
        CLEAR ls_wage_type.
        ls_wage_type-name = <fs_name>.  " Get the wage type name

        LOOP AT <fs_codes> ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_code>).
          APPEND <fs_code> TO ls_wage_type-codes.
        ENDLOOP.

        " Add to internal table
        APPEND ls_wage_type TO lt_wage_types.
      ENDIF.

      " Increment line counter
      lines = lines + 1.
  ENDCASE.

AT SELECTION-SCREEN OUTPUT.
  LOOP AT SCREEN.
    IF screen-group1 CP 'A*'.
      IF screen-group1+1(2) NE lines.
        screen-active = 0.
      ELSE.
        IF lines LT max_lines.
          screen-active = 1.
        ELSE.
          screen-active = 0.
        ENDIF.
      ENDIF.
    ENDIF.
    IF screen-group1 CP 'L*'.
      IF screen-group1+1(2) GT lines.
        screen-active = 0.
      ENDIF.
    ENDIF.
    MODIFY SCREEN.
  ENDLOOP.

INITIALIZATION.
  cnt = 1.
  WHILE cnt LE max_lines.
    CONCATENATE 'PB_' cnt INTO fldname.
    ASSIGN (fldname) TO <fld>.
    <fld> = 'Ajouter'.
    CONCATENATE 'LBL_' cnt INTO fldname.
    ASSIGN (fldname) TO <fld>.
    CONCATENATE 'Rubrique' cnt INTO <fld> SEPARATED BY space.
    cnt = cnt + 1.
  ENDWHILE.

Currently, the user must manually click "Ajouter" to include each wage type. I want to enhance the program so that when a user selects a specific interface variant, the corresponding wage types are preloaded into the input fields without requiring the user to click "Ajouter."
How can I achieve this? Any suggestions or example code would be greatly appreciated!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

The problem cannot be reproduced: the code doesn't compile, it should be minimal (no need repeating 20 times), and if the missing variables are declared there's no "Add" button showing up.

It's not an "Add" button; it's "Ajouter" in French. Regarding the code, this is the one I'm using, and it works fine for me because I declared the variables in another include. As for the repetition 20 times, I couldn't find any other solution besides that.

You need to create a temporary program for supporting the question, which is minimal and reproducible. It also often helps the author to solve the issue before asking. In your case, the solution is to calculate lines at the beginning of the "PBO" (event block at selection-screen output) depending on which inp1001-inp1020 variables contain values. PS: I have adjusted your program in the question to make it compile, but the program doesn't display anything.
